# How to make two small micros communicate with my Arduino over BLE?

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

I want to do a project with an Arduino Uno and two other BLE (or regular bluetooth) capable modules. I want the Bluetooth modules to be hooked up to buttons (one button for each Bluetooth module). I then want the Bluetooth-capable modules to send the state of their buttons to a central Arduino board.

Is this possible? Can I have two different BLE boards connected to one Arduino?

I have a RedBear BLE (Bluetooth low energy) shield for my Arduino. What micro-controllers should I get for the peripheral modules? And where can I learn about pairing Bluetooth modules? Everything I read seems to be about pairing Bluetooth boards to a phone.

Can I do this all with BLE or am I going to need to get a new shield for my Arduino to talk with the two peripheral boards?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SoftwareSerial to communicate with two modules from an uno. But You will have to wire 'em up separately, not through your shield. (making the total number of bluetooth modules 4.

You could also use your existing sheild and poll between the two remotes. I.e. disconnecting from one and connecting to the other at a regular interval.

For the micros and bluetooth for your button, you could use a HM10 with an ATtiny like in [this instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Use-Bluetooth-40-HM10/?ALLSTEPS). He uses two HM10 modules to talk to each other. HM-10 is a popular BLE module. If you want regular bluetooth(2.0), you can use HC-05.

Answer (score 0):

The page for the [RedBear BLE shield](http://redbearlab.com/bleshield/) that you note indicates that the BLE chip is the nRF8001, which it says supports peripheral (slave) role only. This means it must be connected to from a BLE Central role device.

Since you want your Uno to be the central device, listening for data from these 2 remote buttons, your RedBear shield won't work this way.

A [short overview of BLE](https://learn.adafruit.com/introduction-to-bluetooth-low-energy/) is available by AdaFruit.